# sending video stream from client to server with xmlhttpresponse

Tags: javascript, opencv, flask, server, webrtc

I am trying to create a face detection web application.
The app works this way.
1-The user navigates to the url
2-The camera starts on the client machine
3-Each frame is then sent to the server for face detection
4-Processed frame is then displayed on the web page

now my question is this that whenever i am doing this at localhost it is almost running at realtime but when i am hosting this on aws the response time is so less the video lags about so much is there any reason for it or there is any another way to do it which will be good please help .

**html page javascript code to send and receive**

```
    video.addEventListener('play', function() {
            var $this = this; //cache

            // loop function to send video frames continuously
            (function oop() {

            // Till the video is playing
            if (!$this.paused && !$this.ended) {


                console.log($this.videoWidth);
                console.log($this.videoHeight);
                // draws the video frames to the canvas created
                context.drawImage($this, 0, 0,200,200);


                // generates the data from the canvas for each frame
                var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                //sending data using XMLHttpRequest (easy to use)
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                // specify the method = POST for sending 
                // url - which will be recieving our data
                xhr.open("POST","http://127.0.0.1:5000/camera", true);
                // transmit the frame to specified url
                xhr.send(data);
                // console.log(value)


                //receving the frames   
                var str = "data:image/jpeg;base64,";
                var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                request.open('GET','http://127.0.0.1:5000/camera');
                request.responseType = 'text';
                request.onload = function() {   
                    var value = str.concat(request.response);   
                    img.src=value
                    // console.log(value)
                };
                request.send();


                // specify the rate the function will iterate
                setTimeout(oop, 1000 / 30); // drawing at 30fps

            }
            })();

        }, 0);

    }, false);
```

**server side code**

```
    from flask import request, Flask, render_template
    import base64
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    from PIL import Image
    import io
    from flask_cors import CORS


    app=Flask(__name__)
    CORS(app)       # used for cross origin request handling
    # important -- otherwise we won't be able to send image to webpage

    count=0
    main_source=0

    # index function execute when traffic occur at '/'
    @app.route("/")
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html')


    @app.route('/camera', methods=['POST','GET'])
    def camera():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # reading the image (byte stream)
            data=request.stream.read()
            # seperating data from the header {data:image/png;....}
            data=str(data).split(',')[1]

            global count
            global main_source
            count+=1

            ''' starting conversion of html-base64 data to cv-numpy array '''
            # decoding base64 data
            img = base64.b64decode(data)
            # generating numpy array from decoded data
            npimg = np.frombuffer(img, dtype=np.uint8)
            # generating 3d array from 1d
            source = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)
            ''' conversion finished '''


            ''' applying face detection on captured image '''
            # defining classifier --- haarcascade face classifier                                               
            face_cascade=
            cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
            face_img = source.copy()
            # get faces from the image
            face_rects = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(face_img,scaleFactor=1.2)
            # draw rectangle over each face in image
            for (x,y,w,h) in face_rects: 
                cv2.rectangle(face_img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,255,255), 10) 
            ''' face detection finished '''


            ''' conversion of image again to base64 for html '''
            face_img = face_img[...,::-1]                               # bgr to rgb
            im = Image.fromarray(face_img.astype("uint8"), mode='RGB')  # using pillow image library
            rawBytes = io.BytesIO()
            im.save(rawBytes, "JPEG")                                   # saving image to buffer
            rawBytes.seek(0)                                            # return to the start of the file
            encoded_string = base64.b64encode(rawBytes.read())          # read from file buffer and convert to base64
            ''' conversion to base64 finished '''


            main_source=encoded_string
            return ""

        else:
            print("return")
            if type(main_source)==int:
                return ""
            return main_source


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your question why a page over the internet is slower than localhost?

Comment: yes i want that reason and also how can i solve this problem

Comment: Because of [the speed of light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118503/can-internet-speed-be-faster-than-speed-of-light#118514).

Comment: thanks do you know any another way to do it?